# Input tag file value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap 3 model to upload image, when I get value in file field in console I got

```
$('input[type="file"]').val(); // = "C:\fakepath\maxresdefault.jpg"
```

but after send data some time I get value in console

```
$('input[type="file"]').val(); // = ""
```

I got bad result. Whats the problem, but I selected image .and we can see image name in file field but result was empty.how can fix it

Comment: You send data async?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<input type="file" name="uploader" id="uploader">

$(function(){
   $('#uploader').change(function(){
     console.log(this.value);
   });
});
```